# Format the total so it does not show decimal places

Tags: python-3.x

So, I'm trying to make this code not show any decimal places in the end (total)... But I can't really find a way to do it. Is there a way to do it without having to rewrite everything?

```
test1_weight = float(input("Type your 1st Test weight: "))

test2_grade = float(input("Type your 1st Test grade: "))

test2_weight = float(input("Type your 1st Test weight: "))

total = (test1_grade * test1_weight + test2_grade * test2_weight)/(test1_weight + test2_weight)

print ("The weighted average is: ", total)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `total` to an integer:

```
total = int(total)
```

For example:

```
total = 3.75
total = int(total)
print(total) # 3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What I did was 

```print ("The weighted average is: ", int(total))``` 

and it worked too! Have a great day!

Comment: By the way, can I ask you something else here, or do I need to make another post?

Comment: @Opters If it is not related to this question I suggest to open a new one!

Comment: Will do! Need to wait 90 minutes to do so, though. c: 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since each of your inputs are floats, your 'total' will also be a float. If you want the 'total' to not have any decimal points, you should cast total to an integer before printing: `int(total)`

Comment: Hey! Thank you! I got it! 
By the way, if my inputs weren't floats, would I be able to use ```int(total)``` or not? 

Sorry, I'm new to coding stuff :P

Comment: There are three numerical types in Python: floats, integers, and complex numbers. Floats are numbers with decimal places, for example, 3.14. Integers are the numbers without decimal places, for example 3. Complex numbers are a combination of a real part and an imaginary part, for example 3.14 + 0j. Assuming your inputs are numerical you can only use ``int(total)`` if the inputs are already integers or floats. Python can't convert complex numbers to integers. By the way, there are the corresponding functions ``float()`` and ``complex()`` which allow casting of numerical variables.

Comment: It does!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also round the result with the round function

Exemple:

```
round(total)
```

Comment: The `round` function returns a float, not an integer! `round(3.6)` is `4.0`, not `4`. Also, as you can see from my example, it doesn't remove the decimals, but it rounds the number!

Comment: by default, the round function return 0 decimal. If you try type(total) you obtain 'int'. If you want a float number you need to write round(total, digits) with digits the numbet of decimal (0 in default)

Comment: That's what I say! link your first comment. You say that "round return a float" and now an "integer". You can try the round function in W3School with the tryIt editor.

Comment: You should read again the doc of the round function. We are talking about the native function of python (which we use without any import). The round function will return an integer value if the number of decimals is not given!

Comment: It turned out that the behavior of `round` is not the same in all the Python versions. I have tried and got two different results using two different Python versions. So we're both right! Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Indeed ^^ I will pay attention to the Python version so as not to have any surprise! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with f-strings. F-strings allow you to interpolate python expressions with strings, meaning you can stick your variable right in there:

```py
>>> total = 3.75
>>> print(f"The total is: {total}")
```

```
The total is: 3.75
```

It also allows for formatting syntax, which means we can restrict the float to no decimal places by specifying the float format `.0f` after a colon.

```py
>>> total = 3.75
>>> print(f"The total is: {total:.0f}")
```

```
The total is: 4
```

Comment: You're rounding the number. The user wants to remove the decimals without rounding it!

Comment: Where did they say that? It's not in the question or any of their comments...

Comment: Here: "I'm trying to make this code not show any decimal places in the end (total)". Still your answer is valid of course :)

Comment: That doesn't say whether or not they want to round, it just states a purpose. This is closed though, so have a good one.